# Contributing to open source project on github

Tags: git, github

I want to add translation and a bugfix on open source project on github. I had installed git, forked the project, cloned the fork on my harddrive, changed the permissions of the file(needed to do so I can test the changes), then created a new branch called "Bulgarian_language", then added the file "bg.php" which is the translation and changed another file so that the language is visible(I mean to be selected for use), then I used

`git add bg.php`

 then typed

```
git commit -m "Bulgarian language"
```

and nothing happened. Here is the output of git commit

```
 git commit -m "Added Bulgarian language"
 [Bulgarian_language 41e55b8] Added Bulgarian language
 1 file changed, 194 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 languages/bg.php
```

However I don't see the changes on my fork. What I had do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You commit to your local repository; in order for your changes to appear on github, you need to `git push` them.

Comment: I have only one question now, I have to create a pull request so that the maintainer can add the language to the original repo right?